# How to randomize the selection of resources from a pool

Tags: anylogic

I have a resource pool that is defined by nodes in the model network. They represent some staging stations. In my flowchart I seize those stations one at the time for staging. However, the model seems to go over these resources (nodes) by the order they are entered in the pool. Is there a way to make that selection random from the available resources rather than the first available one from the list?

Answer (score 1):

In the seize block, go to *Advanced* options.  Check *Customize resource choice*.  On *Resource Selection* pick *Unit with top rating*.  In *Unit rating,* type in *random()*.

See the help menu for more information about custom resource selection.  In Unit rating, you can also reference unit, if you want to get a value from the individual units to make your selection.  Unit rating can be simple variables or calls to complex functions.